# Django Unit Test Login and Registration

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, authentication, python-behave

I'm new with Django. I would like to write a unit test to test login (and possibly registration) but after several attempts I'm not sure where to start. Would you have any suggestions on how I could write these tests?

Another question is: would be in this case BDD the best choice (with Behave) or should I remain for unit-test here?

Thanks

Code for the view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import login,logout,authenticate

from labs.models import Category

from .forms import createuserform


def index(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
        'categories':categories,
    }

    return render(request, 'landing/index.html', context)


def registerPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/labs') 
    else: 
        form=createuserform()
        if request.method=='POST':
            form=createuserform(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid() :
                user=form.save()
                return redirect('/login')
        context={
            'form':form,
        }
        return render(request,'landing/register.html',context)

def loginPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/labs')
    else:
       if request.method=="POST":
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        user=authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('/')
       context={}
       return render(request,'landing/login.html',context)

def logoutPage(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```